# move an image, display value and saves current value

Tags: javascript, image, get

how can i get the value of how long it moves and save it. so each time someone clicks it it just adds up

```
var imgObj = null;
function init(){

   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
}
function moveRight(){
  if(parseInt(imgObj.style.left) < 700){
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';  
    }
    if(parseInt(imgObj.style.left) == 700){
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 0 + 'px';
    } 
}
window.onload =init;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the move function to execute when someone clicks on the #myImage, use an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). You might use the [advanced model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) or just the [traditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) as you've used it for onload.

```
imgObj.onclick = moveRight; // do not execute
```